# Manipulating and displaying user uploaded image in Flask

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I am working on a web app that allows users to upload their images, they are modified, and then displayed on the web page. Dropzonejs is used to allow users to drag and drop as well as preview their image. The ideal design would be a drag and drop area on one side of the site, and the modified image on the other side once the user clicks the appropriate button. I am new to Flask, and I am not sure what the optimal way is to accomplish this goal. Here is what I have so far.

Here is the Javascript function in the /static folder responsible for one of the buttons responsible for modifying the image.

```
$('#modify1').click(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/transpose",
    data: {input: 1},
    success: function(response) {
      alert("Successful");
      displayImage(response);
      console.log("success");//remove later
    }
});
```

And here is the associated code in the Flask file

```
@app.route("/modify1")
def transpose():
    input_img = request.args.get("input")

    img_mat = np.asarray(input_img, dtype=np.uint8)

    #code to modify img_mat


    img = Image.fromarray(img_mat)

    return img
```

This code does not function correctly, as there is no response when the button is clicked, but is it on the right track? Any suggestions on how to structure and implement this code are very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, your view function `transpose()` is not configured correctly to handle `POST` requests. I'm surprised to see the request go through and not throw `HTTP 405 METHOD NOT ALLOWED`.

Start with this,

```
@app.route("/modify1", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def transpose():
    if flask.request.method == "GET":
        # GET code here
    if flask.request.method == "POST":
        # POST code here
```

See if that changes anything, unfortunately I'm not familiar with any front-end back-end interactions as I only to APIs. This should get you started though.

There are much better and cleaner ways to do this, you can refer to [Flask documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/quickstart/#routing) for hints.

EDIT:

I noticed that you list url as `/transpose` and are using `modify1` as and anchor, but in Flask you have listed `/modify1` to be the `uri`.

Please read the Flask documentation. It's very verbose, presents good examples and also has a tutorial for the most common functionality.